# Change rendering of basic text to use <p></p> instead of <br />

Tags: wiki-markup

WikiPlex renders basic text without adding paragraph `<p>` tags, instead inserting `<br />` where there is a new line.

Unfortunately, this prevents me from being able to target the resultant HTML using CSS.

Is there a way to have WikiPlex render paragraphs properly?